New values of outside variables from "click" event do not persist on the first attempt
I'm working on a to-do project where one can click a button to add a new to-do, or click on an existing card to edit that to-do. I decided to have both use the same form, but with a different "mode" that indicates how the inputs are then processed.
If one clicks on a card after page loads initially then submits changes, the openEditForm function runs and changes the values of outside variables formMode and currentTodo, but when the function finishes, those variables revert to undefined. The problem remains if I cancel to exit the form instead of submitting, then click another card and try to submit changes to that card, as long as I haven't submitted the form once since the initial page load.
The function and outside variables work correctly in any other scenario (adding a new task, clicking on a card after submitting the form at least once regardless of whether it is a new task or a failed edit to an existing card).
I believe the key difference between adding new tasks (which always works correctly) and editing existing cards is that openNewForm doesn't require any parameters, whereas the openEditForm requires parameters to identify which to-do is being edited. I suspect that means the issue is to do with scoping when I add these functions to the relevant "click" events, but I've tried () => openEditForm(project, i) and the current version openEditForm.bind(window, project, i), and can't think of a way to rewrite the function without the parameters.
Any clues? The full code is on Github but here's what I think the most relevant code is, from index.js:
function ScreenController () {
  const todoForm = document.forms["new-todo-form"];
  const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
  const contentDiv = document.querySelector(".content");
  let formMode = "";
  let currentTodo = "";


  // load existing to-dos
  const updateTodos = function (project) {
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "";
    const todos = project.todos;
    
    todos.forEach(function (todo, i) {
      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.classList.add("todo-card");
      card.addEventListener("click", openEditForm.bind(window, project, i));
[...]
  }
[...] 
  const openEditForm  = function (project, index) {
    // BUGS - CURRENTTODO AND FORMMODE DON'T PERSIST IF CARD IS CLICKED AT BEGINNING, passing function into addeventlistener with parameters
    console.log("Open edit form");
    console.log({project, index});
    currentTodo = project.todos[index];
    todoForm.title.value = currentTodo.title;
    todoForm.description.value = currentTodo.description;
    todoForm.dueDate.value = currentTodo.getDueDate();
    todoForm.priority.value = currentTodo.priority;
    
    submitBtn.innerText = "Save task";
    formMode = "edit";
    console.log(formMode);
    toggleForm();
  }
[...]
  // Submit form depending if it is a new or existing to-do

  const submitForm = function () {
    todoForm.reportValidity();

    console.log(formMode);
    switch (formMode) {
      case "add":
        submitTodo();
        break;
      case "edit":
        editTodo(currentTodo);
        break;
    }

    toggleForm();
    updateTodos(defaultProject);
  }
[...]
  // Edit existing to-do
  const editTodo = function(todo) {
    let title = todoForm.title.value;
    let description = todoForm.description.value;
    let dueDate = todoForm.dueDate.value;
    let priority = todoForm.priority.value;

    defaultProject.updateTodo(todo, title, description, dueDate, priority);
  }

Thanks in advance for any help!

How can they revert to undefined? They're initialized as empty strings, so if they revert they should revert to that.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Where are you seeing the undefined formMode, in submitForm()?

Is this happening after you delete todos? That reduces the indexes of all the todos after the one that was deleted. But your event listener is bound to the original indexes, so you may try to access outside the array, which returns undefined. Instead of binding to indexes, bind to the todo item itself.

You can use the <fieldset> element to control what part of the form is displayed/enabled. In this example I have both an "edit" and a "new" fieldset. If the + New to-do is clicked the "new" fieldset will be enabled.
If a fieldset is disabled none of the form fields in that fieldset will be included in the submit event. You can see that the "edit" fieldset has an input hidden id that is only relevant for edits.
The advantage here is that it does not require any global variables -- the form is "self-explanatory" at any point (like, if data.has('id') is true, then it must be an edit).


document.forms.todo_form.add_btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.currentTarget.form;
  form.common.disabled = false;
  form.edit.disabled = true;
  form.new.disabled = false;
});

document.forms.todo_form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  switch(e.target.name){
    case 'cancel_btn':
      let form = e.target.form;
      form.reset();
      form.common.disabled = true;
      form.edit.disabled = true;
      form.new.disabled = true;
      break;
  }
});

document.forms.todo_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let data = new FormData(form);
  
  if(data.has('id')) console.log('must be an edit');
  
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(data));
});
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

fieldset:disabled {
  display: none;
}
<div class="content"></div>

<form id="todo_form">
  <button class="add-btn" name="add_btn" type="button">+<span> New to-do</span></button>
  <fieldset name="common" disabled>
    <label for="title">Title<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder=" " required aria-describedby="required-description">

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder=" " rows="4"></textarea>

    <label for="due-date">Due</label>
    <input id="due-date" type="date" name="dueDate">

    <label for="priority">Priority</label>
    <select id="priority" name="priority">
      <option value="">Please select an option</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
      <option value="high">Medium</option>
      <option value="high">Low</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="edit" disabled>
    <input type="hidden" name="id">
    <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button name="cancel_btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="new" disabled>
    <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Create</button>
    <button name="cancel_btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </fieldset>
  <p aria-hidden="true" id="required-description">
    <span class="required">*</span>Required field
  </p>

</form>



